How do i delete a firebase demo project?
I just clicked on view demo project on firebase for the sake of curiosity and then when i opened the GCP console I saw a new project named firebase demo project (fir-demo-project) which i am unable to delete or do anything with it as it says you don't have permissions to do the action.
I searched on google and stackoverflow and find that clicking the exit demo button at top of firebase console when viewing demo project will delete the project but it does not seem to work for me as i tried doing that but nothing happened.
Also there is no delete project button under project settings in demo projects
Is there any way to delete the demo project?

Show us a screenshot of the project you want to delete.

https://ibb.co/K7hzL5B here is the screenshot

I requested a screenshot of the project from the Firebase Console. It will be helpful to see the  Settings section.

The demo project got removed from my cloud account. I think it took a long time (more than 24 hr) to be removed after exiting the demo from firebase console. BTW Thanks man

If anyone having the same issue, just wait. Sometimes, It actually takes a long time for the demo project to be removed from your cloud console after you exit the demo from firebase.
In my case it took almost more than 24 hours.
